# rclcpp wait for a list of service/action servers to start before proceeding further

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, action-server, ros-service

I have a list of services and a list of actions that I need to wait for to start before I can proceed further. Is there some sort of inbuilt function in `rclcpp` or `rclcpp::Node` that I can use?

Creating a custom service and action client type is not really a viable option for me, since I would have more than 100 services + actions combined.

What I want is something like the following:

```
class SomeNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
    SomeNode() : Node("service_and_action_check")
    {
        /* We do our initial setup */

        std::vector<std::string> serviceList = {"service1", "service2", "service3"};
        std::vector<std::string> actionList  = {"action1", "action2", "action3"};

        for (auto &elem : serviceList)
        {
            checkIfServiceServerIsRunning(elem);
        }

        for (auto &elem : actionList)
        {
            checkIfActionServerIsRunning(elem);
        }

        RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "All services and actions have been loaded.");
    }
    .
    .
    .
};
```

If this is not readily available, if anyone knows of a simple way to create the functions `checkIfServiceServerIsRunning` and `checkIfActionServerIsRunning`, that would be of help too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both services and actions have `wait_for_...()` methods, see the [service tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Writing-A-Simple-Cpp-Service-And-Client.html#write-the-client-node) and rclcpp [source code](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/5ffc963e1aef97928a6cc895db18d40673c655f1/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/client.hpp#L191-L198):

```cpp
while (!client->wait_for_service(1s)) {
    if (!rclcpp::ok()) {
        RCLCPP_ERROR(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "Interrupted while waiting for the service. Exiting.");
        return 0;
    }
    RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "service not available, waiting again...");
  }
```

and the [action client tutorial](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Tutorials/Intermediate/Writing-an-Action-Server-Client/Cpp.html#writing-an-action-client):

```cpp
if (!this->client_ptr_->wait_for_action_server()) {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Action server not available after waiting");
    rclcpp::shutdown();
}
```

`wait_for_action_server()` can also take a duration, see the rclcpp_action [source code](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/5ffc963e1aef97928a6cc895db18d40673c655f1/rclcpp_action/include/rclcpp_action/client.hpp#L83-L86).

For your application you'd have to loop over each of your services/actions and wait untill all are available.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing - storing the service and its type in a `std::pair` and creating a loop that waits for the service until it has been started. The same goes for the action. 

I would have liked a more generalized solution though, something akin to constructing a  list of services and actions at runtime, and then having a templated function that calls the underlying `wait_for_service` or `wait_for_action_server` functions.

Comment: "I would have liked a more generalized solution though,"  -Well, consider implementing this and submitting a pull request to the rclcpp github repository. You already have written most of the code...

Comment: >consider implementing this and submitting a pull request to the rclcpp github repository
Yes, that's the next step. I am currently testing my code, will hopefully be able to make it a bit better in terms of performance.
@JRTG, do you know of a way to get the names of all services and actions running across the ROS network? My current workaround is to have a vector of pairs which I fill by hand. I'd like it to be loaded at runtime though.

Comment: I think you can use `get_service_names_and_types()` for this, see [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/c67720e95c26397cacaf1b4d7fd04cf3785de78a/rclcpp/include/rclcpp/node.hpp#L1261-L1268). The equivalent `get_action_names_and_types()` seems to only exist in `rclpy`, but it should be trivial to port this to `rclcpp` as it is calling `rcl` funcitons, see [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclpy/blob/df92d9e27c3d62bb764ab512ff7e1c53d93c9af1/rclpy/src/rclpy/node.cpp#L567-L578).